# How to convert markdown string to html string with css style exactly like the github preview?

Tags: github, markdown

I'm trying to programmatically parse markdown string to html string in github css style. I've tried things below but none exactly meets my need because of css thing.

1. https://github.com/chjj/marked
2. https://github.com/sindresorhus/github-markdown-css
3. [highlight.js](http://highlightjs.org/)

Compare [my version](https://xiangnanscu.github.io/#/file/%E8%AF%AD%E8%A8%80%E9%AB%98%E4%BA%AE%E6%B5%8B%E8%AF%95.md) to [github version](https://github.com/xiangnanscu/xiangnanscu.github.com/blob/master/%E8%AF%AD%E8%A8%80%E9%AB%98%E4%BA%AE%E6%B5%8B%E8%AF%95.md) you will see that github version is more beautiful. 
So, is there a javascript api which can be used in a html file like this:

````
<script>
// this is a js code block 
var md = "```js\nvar a = 1```" 
var h = Convert(md) 
// h will be the html string just like the one github preview generated 
// (image you submit a github issue and click the preview button)
</script>
````

Or a github api which displays markdown file just like [htmlpreview](http://htmlpreview.github.io/) which displays html file .

Comment: Did you check https://docs.github.com/en/rest/markdown/markdown?

Answer (score 1):

[`ghmd` (GitHub Markdown)](https://pypi.org/project/ghmd/) is a minimal tool (~4 KB) that converts any Markdown file into HTML using the GitHub CSS. It supports both regular Mardkown and GitHub Flavored Mardkown, and adaptive, light and dark modes. **The results look just like they would in GitHub.**

To install it, just run:

```bash
pip install ghmd
```

And to convert any file:

```bash
ghmd README.md --embed-css
```

It will generate a `README.html` in the same directory as the original file. The `--embed-css` flag will embed the CSS styles in the HTML file so it is self-contained. If you are ok with having CSS as a url link, you can skip it, it will be faster and the resulting file will be smaller.

I use it a lot to send Markdown files as HTML and it works like a charm.

**EDIT:** Just to add that I am the author of the tool. I created it because I couldn't find anything that fulfilled my needs: small and looking exactly like GitHub. However, this wasn't intended as a promotion, I truly think it is the best solution for your case, as it was for mine.

Comment: You should mention that you are the author of the tool.

Answer (score 0):

[Highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/) is simply a syntax highlighting framework. You have to include a syntax theme stylesheet to define highlight styles. Github's syntax theme stylesheet is open-sourced and can be found [here](https://github.com/primer/github-syntax-theme-generator) (github-syntax-light). Include this stylesheet in your document and you should be fine.